# What niche would werewolf looking creatures have in an environment?

Tags: evolution, environment, mythical-creatures, ecology

[image: Werewolf from Skyrim.]

By werewolf, I'm not talking about normal humans who can transform into big beasts and transform others to be like them. I'm just purely talking about could the werewolf form be its own wild animal? The werewolf form being a large, bipedal, and carnivorous creature with a canine face and sharp claws that only hunts at night.

The more I think about it, the mythological werewolf actually resembles a bear more than a wolf. But why would a bear-like creature only hunt at night and walk on two legs? And would a creature like this fit any of Earth's biomes?

Comment: VTC because (a) You're allowed to ask one and only one question, (b) you've not provided nearly enough detail to answer the question - or the answer is ridiculously trivial. It appears this is nothing more than a fancy bear, wolf, or gorilla (apex predator) - so it'll displace them somewhere just as we have tigers, lions, pumas, panthers, and other big cats that all fill the same niche in different places. In short, you're asking a Q that's too broad. Do you have a specific Q?

Comment: It's not clear : you ask about werewolves niche in title, but at the same time you give hints of an already existing niche you devised (carnivorous, hunting at night), asking why it would have these. Also, an ecological niche needs a more detailed creature description (your way of seeing werewolves is not necessarily ours), but also needs a biome since it's hyper-bound to it. Therefore, I advise to pick a biome and find their niche there... Or ask if the niche you chose is coherent or not within this environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Aye Aye Captain**

[image]

What you have there is a Giant Ground Aye Aye. These tree dwelling creatures have long front legs for climbing and scary fingernails to get grubs out of tree trunks. They are nocturnal because most animals are nocturnal.

When the Giant Aye Aye's main land predator the Giant Pygmy Goat went extinct due to a natural disaster, they came down from the trees to become the Giant Ground Aye Aye.  They walk upright to not damage their delicate fingernails.

[image]

Mwah!

Comment: I note that in the picture, the ancestral aye-aye is making the same face as the werewolf.  + for evolutionary accuracy.